# sandbox mode in Venmo for Android

Tags: android, payment-gateway, credit-card, venmo

I want to integrate my app with venmo which I have already started using this https://github.com/venmo/app-switch-android. I downloaded two files to start with demo.

After doing it I used this code to display venmo dialog

```
    Intent venmoIntent = VenmoLibrary.openVenmoPayment("APP_NUMBER",
                "MyApp", "venmo@venmo.com", "10",
                "For testing purpose", "Pay");
```

If I do this it displays venmo dialog to make a payment. But I don't know how I can check transection is successful without code. We can check it in code in **onActivityResult** method. But Is there a sandbox mode(something like PayPal) to check payment is successful or not?

Please Help to test with sandbox mode in venmo.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a developer on the android team at Venmo. It's definitely on our roadmap for the future to add a sandbox intent that would do the same app switch but not actually send the payment and return a result code back to your `Activity`. Shoot us an email at `androidteam@venmo.com` and we'll happily get back to you when it's ready.

Comment: Currently How I can test transaction is successful or not ? Is it best to use app switcher or do you guyz have any other better example for this ? Do you have iOS support for sandbox mode?

Comment: Currently it's best if you just make a small transaction with another account to test it. Successfully completing a transaction should give you a `RESULT_OK`, whereas a cancelled or unsuccessful payment would return a `RESULT_CANCELLED` result. We hope to deprecate the app-switch sdk on android soon in favor of a more complete oAuth SDK, but that's a bit farther down the road.